How to hide page header at first page in MS Access report?
I need not to display page header section on first page in MS Access report?
I tried some options from page header section properties and some vba code but it is not giving the required result.
VBA code was tried in "OnLoad", "Page" events.

Set report Page Header property to "Not with Rpt Header".
